# How do solve no matching distribution when installing tensorflow & tensorflow_probability?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I note that there could be similar queries but they don't answer my problem.
I use
Anaconda3 64-bit which uses Python 3.7

Error when installing tensorflow & tensorflow_probability via cmd:

**tensorflow Error**
*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-estimator<2.4.0,>=2.3.0 (from tensorflow) (from versions: 2.2.0)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-estimator<2.4.0,>=2.3.0 (from tensorflow)*

**tensorflow_probability Error**
*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow_probability (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow_probability*

Comment: Please share your commands list or requirements.txt if any.

Comment: `pip install tensorflow` and `pip install tensorflow-probability`. Thanks!